# next() in QSqlQuery returns the last record in the table

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

When search button is clicked, it shows the first record in the table like this;

```
void EditEntry::on_search_button_clicked() {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("database.db");
    bool ok = db.open();
    if (ok) {

        QSqlQuery query1("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE last_name LIKE '%Nana%'");
        if (query1.first()) {
            //show first record in the table where last name like Nana
        }
}
```

I am trying to make the query move to the next record in the table by the click of a button like this;

```
void EditEntry::on_next_button_clicked() {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("database.db");
    bool ok = db.open();
    if (ok) {
        QSqlQuery query1("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE last_name LIKE '%Nana%'");
        if (query1.isActive()) {
            while (query1.next()) {
                //show the next record in the table with last name like Nana
            }
}
```

And showing the previous record with the name like 'Nana' like this;

```
void EditEntry::on_previous_button_clicked() {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("database.db");
    bool ok = db.open();
    if (ok) {
        QSqlQuery query1("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE last_name LIKE '%Nana%'");
        if (query1.isActive()) {
            while (query1.previous()) {
                //show previous record in the table where last name like Nana
            }
}
```

The `on_search_button_clicked()` works well by showing the 1st record with last name like 'Nana'. The `on_next_button_clicked()` shows the last record in the table with name like 'Nana' instead of the next record after the 1st (the table has 3 records with last name like 'Nana'). The `on_previous_button_clicked()` button doesn't work at all, it shows nothing even though i expect it to show the previous record with last name like 'Nana'. How do i get these buttons to work as i expect?

P.S.; what i wanted was, whenever the `on_next_button_clicked()` is clicked it should keep showing the next record till it gets to the last record in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` can only work on one instance of `QSqlQuery` but at the end of `on_search_button_clicked()`, `on_next_button_clicked()` and `on_previous_button_clicked()` you throw away the instance of `QSqlQuery` (as well as `QSqlDatabase`).

I think you could store an offset variable `int offset_ = 0` in the `EditEntry` class and then do something like that

```
void EditEntry::on_next_button_clicked() {
    offset_ += 1;

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("database.db");
    bool ok = db.open();
    if (ok) {
        QString sql = QString("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE last_name LIKE '%Nana%' LIMIT ") + QString::number(offset_) + QString(", 1");
        QSqlQuery query1(sql);
        if (query1.isActive()) {
            while (query1.first()) {
                //show the next record in the table with last name like Nana
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the other one:

```
void EditEntry::on_previous_button_clicked() {
    offset_ -= 1;

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("database.db");
    bool ok = db.open();
    if (ok) {
        QString sql = QString("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE last_name LIKE '%Nana%' LIMIT ") + QString::number(offset_) + QString(", 1");
        QSqlQuery query1(sql);
        if (query1.isActive()) {
            while (query1.first()) {
                //show the next record in the table with last name like Nana
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this time, it doesn't do anything at all. If i do the storing of the offset variable in the class header, i get an error from the compiler telling me to make it static and all that. So i stored the offset in the constructor. But as i said, It doesn't work.

Comment: OK! got it to work but what i wanted was, whenever the button is clicked it should keep showing the next record till it gets to the last record in the table? `on_next_button_clicked()`. This just lets it do it once. Sorry for that, i added it to my question

Comment: And you were saying something about throwing away instance of `QSqlQuery` as well as `QSqlDatabase`. Can you please elaborate on that, I'm lost!

Comment: I happen to get the `on_next_button_clicked()` working perfect now, i just was having problems with the `offset_` but it's ok now. About the `on_previous_button_clicked()`, how do i go about it?

Comment: @PaaK Do the same as in `on_next_button_clicked()` but reduce the offset `offset_ -= 1;` first. Then it will drop from e.g. 4 to 3 and the following sql gets the 3rd row.

Comment: @PaaK I added the implementation of  `on_previous_button_clicked()`